Making a node in TikZ occupy no space - at least as far as centering the diagram on the page is concerned
The text in the node on the right side of the diagram of code for a TikZ diagram is pushing the graph leftwards. I am enclosing the text in \makebox[0pt]. I thought that doing so would get TikZ to ignore the space occupied by the text and center the graph horizontally on the page.
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=5in, axis equal image, unit vector ratio=4 5,
    xmin=-9,xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=7,
    restrict y to domain=-6:7,
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=none
]

%The following plot is that of a parabola. Its focus is located and its directrix is drawn.
\addplot[samples=501, domain={-2*(1+sqrt(6))}:{2*(sqrt(6)-1)}] {-1/4*(x+2)^2 + 3};
\addplot [samples=2, dashed, latex-latex, domain=-5:7] (-2,x);


\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-9:5] {4};
\coordinate (label for directrix) at (5.15,4);
\path node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0] at (label for directrix){$\ell$};


\coordinate (F) at (-2,2);
\coordinate (P) at (2,-1);
\node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] at (P){$P$};




\end{axis}




\draw[fill] (F) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (an_end_of_a_pin) at ($(F) +(225:{4/3})$);
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (F) -- (an_end_of_a_pin) node[anchor=north, align=center, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0]{Focus\\$F$};


\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dash dot] (F) -- (P);
\draw[dash dot] (P) -- (Q);


\path node[text width=0.4\linewidth, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.east) +(1,0)$){\makebox[0pt]{$P$ is an arbitrary point}\\\makebox[0pt]{that is equidistant}\\\makebox[0pt]{from $F$ and $\ell$}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Your code does not compile

Thanks for commenting out a command for me.

You can use the overlay option to prevent a node from influencing the bounding box:
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}




\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=5in, axis equal image, unit vector ratio=4 5,
    xmin=-9,xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=7,
    restrict y to domain=-6:7,
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=none
]

%The following plot is that of a parabola. Its focus is located and its directrix is drawn.
\addplot[samples=501, domain={-2*(1+sqrt(6))}:{2*(sqrt(6)-1)}] {-1/4*(x+2)^2 + 3};
\addplot [samples=2, dashed, latex-latex, domain=-5:7] (-2,x);


\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain=-9:5] {4};
\coordinate (label for directrix) at (5.15,4);
\path node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0] at (label for directrix){$\ell$};


\coordinate (F) at (-2,2);
\coordinate (P) at (2,-1);
\node[anchor=west, font=\footnotesize] at (P){$P$};




\end{axis}




\draw[fill] (F) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (an_end_of_a_pin) at ($(F) +(225:{4/3})$);
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (F) -- (an_end_of_a_pin) node[anchor=north, align=center, font=\footnotesize, inner sep=0]{Focus\\$F$};


\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[dash dot] (F) -- (P);
%\draw[dash dot] (P) -- (Q);


\node[overlay,text width=0.4\linewidth, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.east) +(1,0)$){$P$ is an arbitrary point that is equidistant from $F$ and $\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


